# Print length of word from text file

Tags: php, html-table

I am pretty new to PHP and I have created a simple script that collects data from a text file and prints it in a table.

The data in the text file looks like this:

```
0086.se 2017-04-02
0102design.se 2017-03-03
0141.se 2017-04-21
0158.se 2017-03-27
```

The output looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Name</td><th>Date</td></tr>
<tr><td>0086.se</td><td>2017-04-02</td></tr>
<tr><td>0102design.se</td><td>2017-03-03</td></tr>
<tr><td>0141.se</td><td>2017-04-21</td></tr>
<tr><td>0158.se</td><td>2017-03-27</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</td>
        <th>Date</td>
    </tr>
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("domaner.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('  ', $line_of_text);
    echo "<tr><td>$parts[0]</td><td>$parts[1]</td></tr>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to add one more TD after the date column that prints out the length of the word in the Name column, but, not counting ".se". For example 0086.se would give the length 4. Like this:

```
<tr><td>0086.se</td><td>2017-04-02</td><td>THE LENGHT OF 0086 HERE</td></tr>
```

I hope someone understand what I am trying to achieve here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Lenght</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("domaner.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
    $tmp = explode('.', $parts[0]);
    echo "<tr><td>".$parts[0]."</td><td>".$parts[1]."</td><td>".strlen($tmp[0])."</td></tr>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me the value 0 on all table rows.

Comment: The first explode as a double space instead of one, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the number that you're looking for!

echo strlen($parts);

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me how to include it in the code? I can't get it to work I am afraid.

Comment: @laurent-ub gave you an absolutely wonderful implementation, including exactly how to include it into your code. I'd follow his/her answer - it's better than my initial thought.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your echo to this one

```
 echo "<tr><td>$parts[0]</td><td>$parts[1]</td><td>iconv_strlen($parts[0])-3</td></tr>";
```